# Regex @mention including .com without final

Tags: regex

How to match a @mention with and without suffix domain name ('@leïa' and '@Leïa@starwars.com' are valid) but without to get the last '.'?

Regex: `/@([A-Za-z0-9_çéàèùâêîôûëïüÇÉÀÈÙÂÊÎÔÛËÏÜ@.]+)/ig`

Sample:

> @Luke is the brother of @Leïa@starwars.com, and they are the both
> children of @DarthVather.

Expected:

> @Luke, @Leïa@starwars.com and @DarthVather (without the final '.')

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
@[A-Za-z0-9_çéàèùâêîôûëïüÇÉÀÈÙÂÊÎÔÛËÏÜ]+(?:[.@][A-Za-z0-9_çéàèùâêîôûëïüÇÉÀÈÙÂÊÎÔÛËÏÜ]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K6fW6f/1).

*Details*:

- `@` - a `@` char
- `[A-Za-z0-9_çéàèùâêîôûëïüÇÉÀÈÙÂÊÎÔÛËÏÜ]+` - one of the selected letters, digits, underscores
- `(?:[.@][A-Za-z0-9_çéàèùâêîôûëïüÇÉÀÈÙÂÊÎÔÛËÏÜ]+)*` - zero or more occurrences of a `.` or `@` followed with one of the selected letters, digits, underscores.

In Python 3, you can simplify this to

```py
results = re.findall(r'@\w+(?:[.@]\w+)*', text)
```

You do not need `re.U` / `re.UNICODE` since it is on by default.

Comment: Great. I could use `\w` instead of mentioning individual characters in Python. Does it have any pitfall ? Interestingly `r"@\w+(?:[.@]\w+)*"` works with or without `re.UNICODE` flag. I thought it should work only with this flag. My interpreter version : 3.10.4

Comment: @S.B I updated the answer with the Python solution.

Comment: BTW, if you can use PyPi regex module, if you can install the regex module with `pip install regex`, then you can use something like `regex.findall(r'@[\p{L}\p{M}0-9_]+(?:[.@][\p{L}\p{M}0-9_]+)*', text)`.